# Finding the max value in Python Column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame (`combined_ranking_df`) like this in pandas python:

```
                Id  Rank                         Activity
0              14035   8.0                         deployed
1              47728   8.0                         deployed
2              24259   1.0                         NaN
3              24259   6.0                         WIP
4              14251   8.0                         deployed
5              14250   1.0                         NaN
6              14250   6.0                         WIP
7              14250   5.0                         NaN
8              14250   5.0                         NaN
9              14250   1.0                         NaN
```

I am trying to get the max value for each id. for example, 14250 it should be 6.0. 24259 it should be 6.0.

```
                Id  Rank                         Activity
0              14035   8.0                         deployed
1              47728   8.0                         deployed
3              24259   6.0                         WIP
4              14251   8.0                         deployed
6              14250   6.0                         WIP
```

I tried doing `combined_ranking_df.groupby(['Id'], sort=False)['Rank'].max()` but the result i achieved was the first `dataframe` (nothing changed).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

**Option 1**
Same as @ayhan's answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45059805/2336654)
This answers the question by sorting the dataframe that leaves the maximal value in the last position per `'Id'` group.  `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates` enables us to keep the first or last of each group.  However, this is a handy coincidence that is very fast.  It does not generalize to say the top two per `'Id'`.

```
df.sort_values('Rank').drop_duplicates('Id', 'last')

      Id  Rank  Activity
3  24259   6.0       WIP
6  14250   6.0       WIP
0  14035   8.0  deployed
1  47728   8.0  deployed
4  14251   8.0  deployed
```

---

You can sort the index at the end

```
df.sort_values('Rank').drop_duplicates('Id', 'last').sort_index()

      Id  Rank  Activity
0  14035   8.0  deployed
1  47728   8.0  deployed
3  24259   6.0       WIP
4  14251   8.0  deployed
6  14250   6.0       WIP
```

---

**Option 2**
`groupby` and `idxmax`
This is what I'd consider the most idiomatic way to solve this problem.  @MaxU's answer is the best way that generalizes to the largest `n` per `'Id'`.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Id', sort=False).Rank.idxmax()]

      Id  Rank  Activity
0  14035   8.0  deployed
1  47728   8.0  deployed
3  24259   6.0       WIP
4  14251   8.0  deployed
6  14250   6.0       WIP
```

Comment: Hi I tried doing this but it still the same. Is the datatype of my column wrong or something?

I did this:

groups = combined_ranking_df.loc[combined_ranking_df.groupby('Id', sort=False).Rank.idxmax()]

Comment: You tell me!  Run `combined_ranking_df.dtypes` and see if `'Rank'` is `float`

Comment: If not, run this instead `combined_ranking_df.loc[combined_ranking_df.groupby('Id', sort=False).Rank.astype(float).idxmax()] `

Answer (score 6):

IIUC:

```
In [40]: df.groupby('Id', as_index=False, sort=False) \
           .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, ['Rank'])) \
    ...:   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
Out[40]:
      Id  Rank  Activity
0  14035   8.0  deployed
1  47728   8.0  deployed
2  24259   6.0       WIP
3  14251   8.0  deployed
4  14250   6.0       WIP
```

or a nicer version from [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064130/finding-the-max-value-in-python-column/45064170?noredirect=1#comment77102645_45064170):

```
In [41]: df.groupby('Id', group_keys=False, sort=False) \
           .apply(pd.DataFrame.nlargest, n=1, columns='Rank')
Out[41]:
      Id  Rank  Activity
0  14035   8.0  deployed
1  47728   8.0  deployed
3  24259   6.0       WIP
4  14251   8.0  deployed
6  14250   6.0       WIP
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Id', group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.nlargest, n=1, columns='Rank')`

Comment: @piRSquared, i totally forgot about `group_keys` parameter - thanks a lot!

Comment: I've got your back!

Answer (score 4):

Try storing it and then consult that stored `groupedby`

```
groups = combined_ranking_df.groupby(['Id'], as_index=False, sort=False).max()[['Id','Rank']].

      Id  Rank
0  14035   8.0
1  47728   8.0
2  24259   6.0
3  14251   8.0
4  14250   6.0
```

Comment: `sort=False` parameter to get OP's output

Answer (score 3):

You can create a boolean index to check if the `Rank` for a given `Id` equals its max value.  Then use boolean indexing to extract the max values from the dataframe.

The mask is created using a `groupby` on `Id` with the help of `transform`, which preserves the original dimensions of the dataframe.

```
>>> df[(df[['Rank']] == df[['Id', 'Rank']].groupby('Id').transform(max)).squeeze().tolist()]
      Id  Rank  Activity
0  14035     8  deployed
1  47728     8  deployed
3  24259     6       WIP
4  14251     8  deployed
6  14250     6       WIP
```

Comment: I've learned so much from your answers... I wish I saw them more often (-:

Comment: Very interesting and unusual approach - i really like it!